# How to print and style mathematica results in text

Tags: printing, styles, wolfram-mathematica, output

How can I print a line of text with the results of some variable and still edit the font size and font color? Something like this:

```
Style[
      "The equation result was ", Returns, 
      "% running from ",DateString[TableDate[[1]],
      {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort", ", ", "Year"}]
, 15, Red]
```

I wanted something like:
*The equation result was 35% running from January 15, 2000*

But in red and in a bigger font size! Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Returns = 35;
TableDate = {{2000, 1, 15}};

Style[StringJoin["The equation result was ", ToString@Returns,
  "% running from ", DateString[TableDate[[1]],
   {"MonthName", " ", "DayShort", ", ", "Year"}]], 20, Red]
```

Comment: 15 is a small font on my screen so I changed it to 20.  Hope you don't mind. +1